# Rspec routing test not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

The below rspec test is not passing, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It routes fine in the browser, but the test is not passing.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe QueueVideosController do
  describe "GET show" do
    context "with authenticated users" do
      it "routes /queue to the QueueVideos controller" do
        expect(get("/queue")).to route_to("queue_videos#show")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

From my controller:

```
class QueueVideosController < ApplicationController
 def show
 end
end
```

From my routes file:

```
 get '/queue' => 'queue_videos#show'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different syntax:

```
expect(get: "/queue").to route_to(
  controller: "queue_videos",
  action: "show"
)
```